# Create list object from multiline input with only the standard python library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to store this single input:

```
5 2 100
2
8
1
3
```

into three variables (N, x, n) and a list object

the variables are correctly written, being `N = 5, x = 2, n = 100`

---

```
N, x, n = input().split(' ')
list = [input()]
```

I've tried using this, but the list only intakes the `['2']`, while I need it to be `['2', '8', '1', '3']`

I've also tried using while and if loops to try to iterate through the input,
but that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: In order to construct the list, you will have to invoke *input()* multiple times. You will then have to figure out how may times you do that (for loop?) or use some special value to indicate that you're done

Comment: alternatively, you can have the user input the list as comma separated values and then process the string to create the desired list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enter the list you use this approach:

```
N, x, n = input().split(' ')
lst = []
while True:
    el = input()
    if len(el) > 0:
        lst.append(el)
    else:
        break
```

Note that you'll have a list of strings, and also `N`, `x` and `n` are strings - so will need to take care of it...